# Qt Dynamic Plugin Fails to Load, Undefined Symbol

Tags: qt, plugins

I have a project where I'm trying to use custom Qt plugins. I have a Timer interface which is the plugin interface (its just callled Timer). This interface has two methods, read/write which specify the use of a class which is defined in another dll (StreamReader, StreamWriter). I've implemented the TimerInterface and tried loading the plugin but I get the error message.

Cannot load library libCountDownTimerd.so: undefined symbol: _ZN9CountDown4readERKSt10shared_ptrI15StreamReaderE).

So obviously there is a problem with my read method. The application itself is loading the library at link time (I have a LIBS += ....). The Timer interface and its countdown implementation link to the library as well.

I'm a bit lost as to how the symbol could be undefined. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks,

Jec

Comment: Is your `StreamReader` class marked for export?

Comment: Yes. I am running this on Linux so as far as I know that's not necessary. I was going to mass 'export' classes when I got this project to a milestone.